# How would you reparametrize a worldline in terms of proper time in 2-dimensional Minkowski spacetime?

Tags: general-relativity, special-relativity, spacetime, metric-tensor, geodesics

In a 2-dimensional Minkowski spacetime i.e. $x^\mu=(t,x)$, you can define the metric simply by the Minkowski metric, $ds^2=-dt^2+dx^2$, and the Christoffel symbols vanish. If you have a worldline described by $\gamma^\mu(\lambda)=(\lambda,a)$ where $\lambda$ has its usual meaning and $a$ is a real constant, how would you go about parametrizing the worldline in terms of proper time $\tau$ such that you find an expression in the form of $\gamma^\mu(\tau)$?

Comment: Isn't your $t$ here your proper time? Your worldline is $x=Constant$ with $t$ arbitrary.